# Replace semi-colon with nothing if NOT preceded by " (double quote)

Tags: string, t-sql, replace, str-replace, sql-server-2019

I have a string like  `"Column";"Column";"Column"`.

However, several times I see:

​`"Column";"Column;";"Column"`

(Notice the extra semicolon in the second field).

Is it  possible to find all instances where  a semicolon (`;`) is not surrounded by double quotes (`"`) and  replace these with nothing?

something like `replace(@string,'[a-z][0-9];','')` ?

`"Column";"Column;";"Column`" turns into `"Column";"Column";"Column"`

`"Value";"Value;";"Value"` turns into `"Value";"Value";"Value"`

`"Something";";Something else;";"Another ;thing"` turns into `"Something";"Something else";"Another thing"`

Comment: You need regex to do this properly, TSQL is not very good at that kind of thing

Comment: Meaning? Outside of my TSQL script? Or using inline code?

Comment: Preferably outside, but you could use an SQLCLR function if you want to go down that road

Comment: *Normally* if your delimiter appear *inside* the double quotes that means it's part of the value; are you sure you want to remove these characters? It could be likely you would be changing the value and you don't want to do that.

Comment: @Larnu I understand your concerns and worries. SOmehow I would like to explain to you what I am doing but I am not comfortable doing that through comments and answers. Is there some way on Stack to send DM's?

Comment: *"Is there some way on Stack to send DM's?"* No, and that is by design. If it's important to the question, put it in the question.

Comment: I was afraid so. Too bad. but understandable. I will see if I can post in it's entirety what I am working on so it might make sense to you. In the meantime, assume for this question that those semi-colons that are not surrounded by " can safely be removed.

Comment: *"assume for this question that those semi-colons that are not surrounded by " can safely be removed"* So what is your delimiter if the delimiter can be safely removed?

Comment: the delimiters are supposed to be surrounded by double quotes.
The string "value;";"another value";"third value" contains two delimiters and three semi-colons.  So you can say that any delimitier symbol contained within doublequotes is not a delimiter. SSIS works that way. BULK INSERT too.

Comment: So is your delimiter *actually* `";"` *not* `;`? Otherwise you aren't making sense here. If you want to remove the `;` not surrounded by double quotes in the string `"Column";"Column;";"Column"` you end up with `"Column""Column;""Column"`.

Comment: OK. Imagine it is a string. 
"Column";"Column;";"Column" is what I have, how can I turn this into "Column";"Column";"Column" ?
"Value";"Value;";"Value" turns into "Value";"Value";"Value"
"Something";";Something else;";"Another ;thing" turns into "Something";"Something else";"Another thing"

Comment: [Edit] your question, @Henrov ...

Comment: Note your question is a little confusing, you are saying you want to remove the semi colons ***not*** surrounded by quotes, but in your expected results the ones you are removing are the ones surrounded by them. In the value `"Column";"Column";"Column"` there are *no* `;` characters surrounded by `"`; they are all outsides of the quotes. If you did what you stated, and removed the `;` characters *not* surrounded by `"` then you would end up with `"Column""Column""Column"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233167/discussion-between-henrov-and-larnu).

Comment: With respect, until you [edit] your question to explain what the *real* problem is, there's little point entering a chat; the information should be in the question, not a chat. Though I have now answered the question based on what I *think* you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is oversimplification, but if you really have that string in a @string then I see no reason this shouldn't work:

```
replace(@string, ';";"', '";"')
```

Comment: This *does* assume that the semicolon can't appear in the middle of the value, and that the last "column" won't contain a semicolon either.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your table's definition, this is a vague answer.

In SQL Server 2017 (if I recall correctly), support for CSV formats were added to `BULK INSERT`, meaning that you could specify both your column and row separators *and* quote identifiers. For the above, this would mean your `FIELDTERMINATOR` would need the value `';'` and the `FIELDQUOTE` would need the value `'"'`. This will, however, leave the remaining `;` characters that are surrounded in double quotes.

As such, what I would propose is to create a staging table, where all the columns are a `(n)varchar`, `BULK INSERT` your data into that and then `INSERT` the data into your production table, with `REPLACE` operators to remove the remaining `;` characters and strongly typing them.

In pseudo-SQL this would look like something like this:

```sql
BULK INSERT Staging.YourTable
FROM 'C:\YourFilePath\YourFile.txt'
WITH (FORMAT='CSV',
      FIELDQUOTE='"',
      FIELDTERMINATOR=';');

INSERT INTO Production.YourTable (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4)
SELECT REPLACE(Column1,';',''),
       TRY_CONVERT(int,REPLACE(Column2,';','')),
       TRY_CONVERT(date,REPLACE(Column3,';',''),103),
       REPLACE(Column4,';','')
FROM Staging.YourTable;
```